# Symfony2 custom security voter not working

Tags: security, symfony

I implementend my own security voter for my symfony (2.6.1) based project. I did so following this blog entry: http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-6-simpler-security-voters and this documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html

My problem now is, that the method "isGranted" of my voter never gets called.

My voter class looks like this:

```
namespace AppBundle\SecurityVoter;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\AbstractVoter;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class FolderVoter extends AbstractVoter
{
    const EDIT = 'edit';

    protected function getSupportedClasses()
    {
        return array('\MyApp\Entity\Folder');
    }

    protected function getSupportedAttributes()
    {
        return array(self::EDIT);
    }

    protected function isGranted($attribute, $folder, $user = null)
    {
        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            return false;
        }

        if ($folder->getUserId() == $user->getId()) {

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

The class is configured in the services.yml in the following way:

```
security.access.folder_voter:
class: AppBundle\SecurityVoter\FolderVoter
public: false
tags:
  - { name: security.voter }
```

I'm using the method 'is_granted' from within a twig template. What did i miss to implement or what did i do wrong that it is not working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution myself. It was pretty easy. But nasty in some way as well.

Insted of this:

```
protected function getSupportedClasses()
{
    return array('\MyApp\Entity\Folder');
}
```

I had to declare the class name like this. So without the leading backslash:

```
protected function getSupportedClasses()
{
    return array('MyApp\Entity\Folder');
}
```

Maybe this could be improved on the security voter implementation in general :-)

Comment: If you think it should then you should raise an issue on the github repository.